# services - how to handle import {environment} only once?

Tags: angular

I have 10 services and in each i import:

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
```

Is it possible to handle the import once somewhere above and use it in all of the  services?

Comment: What is the concern/issue with importing it multiple times (once in each file that uses it)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using [InjectionTokens](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken), but it would be less performant than just importing it directly from the file.